# Non-generic collections in Java - any uses?

Tags: java, generics, collections

Are there any situations where it's better to use a non-generic collection in Java rather then generic (or they still exist only for backward-compatibility)?

Comment: As far as I'm aware no; you should always use the generic versions (it's a compiler warning, too).

Comment: AFAIK, to support legacy code could only be the reason.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR Even then, wouldn't the code still work since Generics compiles to just casting of Object?

Comment: Well, they may still serve a purpose in tutorials about generics.

Comment: @TheLQ The point is to allow the legacy code without generics to be correctly compiled using JDK5+ without any changes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Absolutely not. In the case in which you can't infer types at declaration time, use a `?` as a type specifier - that's what it is for. (There are cases where using `?` would restrict you from invoking certain methods, such as `List.add()`. In such cases, you can find a more restrictive type specifier; `Object` usually works).

The non-generic usage is still supported because, technically, there is nothing wrong in *not* using it; you're just going to end up writing more casting instructions and put yourself in a higher risk for `ClassCastException`'s, but it is technically legitimate as far as the specification is concerned.

Overall, there is no case (that I can think of) where avoiding generics is "better than" using them. At the worst case (when you must use `?` or `Object` at declaration time), both approaches are equal.

Comment: Right, and there possibly are other instances where you can't use `?` as a type specifier. However, for such cases, you should be able to use something more restrictive than `?` (such as `Object`) as a type specifier. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: `ArrayList and LinkedList` can't even be instantiated with `?` as the type specifier.  @Isaac For the answer to apply to the question, you should explain the benefit of using `<Object>`, when it's the equivalent (minus the compiler warnings) of having an untyped collection?  I say this because having an Object-type collection experiences the same disadvantages your answer presents for an untyped collection.

Comment: @Vulcan `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` can't be *instantiated* with `?`, but can  be *declared* as such. The main benefit of using generics is at the declarative aspect, not instantiation, but that's immaterial for the question. The question asks about whether there's a case in which not using generics is (quote) *better* than over using them. At the worst case scenario (of using `?` or `Object`), both approaches are identical (as you said; same disadvantages). I can't think of a case when avoiding generics is better than using them. I edited my answer accordingly; thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Most important, generics are compile-time only, runtime behavior and performance are not affected by generics at all. So neither is *better*, it’s just a matter of personal preference.